# C++ tie one variable to two others via references

Tags: c++, variables, reference

In C++, we can define a variable by reference like:

```
int foo = 3;
int &bar = foo;
```

Then, the following code

```
cout << foo << " " << bar;
```

will print

```
3 3
```

because the "value" of bar is tied to the value of foo by reference(&). I'm wondering, is there a way to tie the value of "bar" to two variables? Say I have three variables: geddy, neil, and alex, and I want neil to always equal alex + geddy. Is there a way two write something like:

```
int alex = 4;
int geddy = 5;
int &neil = alex + geddy;
```

So that neil will return 9? Then, if I change alex to 7, neil will return 12?

Comment: c++ does not work the way you want. `neil` will not dynamically change its value after the assignment if `alex` or `geddy` change. There is no syntax to make that happen.

Comment: Isn't this just a function?  Besides, what would happen if you tried to assign something to `neil`?

Comment: I think "complete nonsense" is a bit harsh. I misplaced an "&". Anyway, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not really. You could make a function or functor though:

```
int alex = 4;
int geddy = 5;

auto neil = [&]() { return alex + geddy; };
std::cout << neil() << "\n";
```

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. But if that's the best I've got, I'll have to figure out how to work with it. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewWatson: You can automate the `()` call as a conversion operator on an object of class type, so you can get the notation that you apparently want. But making things implicit is often an Ungood Idea™, especially when it doesn't remove verbosity. In `std::cout << neil() << "\n"` a reader can see what this does, that there is a function call, but in `std::cout << neil << "\n"` the call is not apparent. That said, it sounds as if you really want *spreadsheet* functionality, not a C++ program. A spreadsheet can be a good *ad hoc* solution to a practical problem.